# std::string not nothrow move assignable or comparable?

Tags: c++, type-traits

I was playing around with `type_traits`, and I discovered this strange property of `std::string`:

```
$ cat a.cpp
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<std::string>::value, "???");
static_assert(noexcept(std::declval<std::string>() == std::declval<std::string>()), "???");
$ g++ -std=c++14 a.cpp
a.cpp:4:1: error: static assertion failed: ???
 static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<std::string>::value, "???");
 ^
a.cpp:5:1: error: static assertion failed: ???
 static_assert(noexcept(std::declval<std::string>() == std::declval<std::string>()), "???");
 ^
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Yet cppreference claims the [move assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) and [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) are marked `noexcept`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

Comment: Maybe just a bad implementation. Looks like [it works](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/L8ZGpMveSiBnNj7a) in GCC 6.

Comment: Might be a libstdc++ bug in my version then. I wonder what version that uses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Yet cppreference claims the move assignment operator and comparison operators are marked `noexcept`.

There was a defect report about this, because C++11 said the move assignment was `noexcept` but that was impossible to satisfy in general (because it might need to reallocate if moving from a string with an incompatible allocator that doesn't propagate). See [DR 2063](https://wg21.link/lwg2063).

The standard has been fixed so that the exception specification depends on the properties of the allocator, and but until that new rule was implemented in GCC we did not make the operations `noexcept`. I implemented the fixed rules for GCC 6.1 (see [PR 58265](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58265)) and backported the change to the gcc-5-branch, but there hasn't been another release of GCC 5.x since then. It will be fixed in the 5.5 release, whenever that happens.